# 'body' property missing on rxjs observable catch error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I have recently upgraded my react-native version from 0.59 to 0.62 after doing that I found that my Observable catch error is missing the body property, I have not made any code change and thus the current code is breaking due to the absence of body property, rest all properties are showing up

Response:-

```
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {map: {…}}
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: undefined
type: "default"
url: "http://localhost:15203/test/oauth2/tokens"
_bodyBlob: Blob {_data: {…}}
_bodyInit: Blob {_data: {…}}
__proto__: Object
```

Code:-

```
Observable.merge(
          .mergeMap(() => Observable.of<any>(testSuccess()))
          .catch((error: any) => handleError(error))
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I found the loophole, the issue was with the finally method, recent react-native versions has made some changes on finally method and it seems that they have stopped accepting arguments, so as a result my condition was breaking due to the unavailability of argument.

I made some changes in the condition to make it work